# How many zeros are there at the end of 196^196, when expressed in base 7?

Tags: number-theory

The answer is 392. I just want to know the concept behind this question. By zeroes what they mean really.

Comment: The base-seven representation of $196$ is $400$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You should choose your tags carefully. What has this to do with `logarithms`?

Comment: Link for basic MathJax tutorial :
https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

MathJax improves the formatting of the mathematical expressions in your question. At MSE, users prefer that people use MathJax.

Answer (score 2):

The number of zeroes at the end of a number, in base $10$, is essentially the highest power of $10$ that perfectly divides the number. The analogy is similar in base $7$. We need to calculate the power of $7$ dividing $196^{196}$. We have:
$$196^{196}=(4 \cdot 7^2)^{196}=4^{196} \cdot 7^{392}$$
The above prime factorization justifies that the answer is $392$.